# html audio - manually stop audio, raising ended event

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Can I stop an html audio manually in a way that it raises the "ended" event?

```
<script>
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?&q=text&tl=en&client=a"
    audio.play();

    audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
        console.log("audio ended");
    });

    audio.addEventListener("play", function() {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            audio.pause();  //stop audio half sec after it starts - this doesn't raise the "ended" event!
        }, 500);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Then you're not looking for `ended`, you're looking for the `pause` event!

Comment: Why do you want to raise the ended event? you could just call the code you would call from your ended event handler at the end of your setTimeout in the "play" listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but its on `timeupdate` event folowing code with jQuery and JS respectively

```
<audio ontimeupdate="watchTime4Audio(this.currentTime,this.duration)" ... ></audio>
```

IN HTML

```
//jQuery
$('audio').on('timeupdate',function(){
    if($(this).prop('currentTime')>=$(this).prop('duration')){
        //the song has ended you can put your trigger here    
    }
});

//JS
audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
    if(this.currentTime >= this.duration){
         //the song has ended you can put your trigger here    
    }
});
```

Using Javascript/JQuery

Comment: this is causing the audio is lagging.. any solution ???